# How can I control the frequency of synchronization with Google?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, sync

My phone syncs with Google pretty often.  Each time it takes a few minutes and makes the whole phone work slowly.

Is there any way to make the synchronization less frequent?

Barring that, is there any way to make it pause when I actually want to *use* the phone?  Is there any way to lower the priority of the sync tasks?

I'm using a Samsung Galaxy S with Froyo.

Comment: You might want to review whether you have any apps that sync that you don't really need. I have turned off background sync on my Twitter and Facebook clients (and let them sync when I launch them), and set the time intervals as high as reasonable on others that offer that choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that Matthew Read is correct about there being no native way to sync this, and about Locale's ability to work around this, but I'm going to suggest some cheaper and simpler alternatives to the $10 Locale app:

**[Tasker](https://market.android.com/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) ($6.50):** Basically the same as Locale but cheaper.   With this (and probably Locale) **you could set a profile that turns on AutoSync for only 5 minutes and repeats this every hour (or whatever timeframe you want).** Also, Tasker can use Locale plugins.

**[JuiceDefender](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.latedroid.juicedefender) (free):** I've used it before (although never tried what you are trying to do) and it's super easy to setup and use.  It allows you to control total connectivity and app by app connectivity control.  It also claims to allow you to schedule "Synchronization Events", which I've never tried by sounds like it would control general and app specific syncing.

**[Sync Schedule](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.ebserver.syncschedule) (free):**  I don't think this will be as useful as the name suggests but if all else fails it's worth a shot.  It allows you to set times for the autosync to turn off and on but I'm not sure if it lets you set multiple time windows per day so this may be of limited use.

Also regarding your *"is there any way to make it pause when I actually want to use the phone?"* question, **the native Android Power Control Widget has an Autosync as one of the options allowing  you to toggle it on/off at will**.

Comment: @TomG: I think this comment would be better suited for the question than this answer, especially so the OP gets notified about it.

Comment: thanks.  I was thinking it of it as a supplement to your answer, but it does make sense with the question, so I've moved it up there.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know of any way to set the sync frequency or to make syncing low-priority, unfortunately.  You could use Locale to turn off/on auto-sync based on profiles you set up, however.  There's a Locale plugin that might do most of the work for you: https://market.android.com/details?id=net.andvari.android.syncsetting