# Sync without gmail playing big brother?

Tags: sync, privacy, offline

My happiness turned to despire when I realised that to have Android0based cell means to have a mandatory GMail account and an mandatory sync of all data to Google even if one just wants to sync just PC and cell in good old fashioned way. :(

I am not comfortable being forced to use GMail, moreover I don't want an online sync! I just want my phone and my PC to be in sync. Is there any other good way to achieve this without smashing my cell to pieces and hating Google for the rest of my life?

I am really unhappy that Google is this ruthless for data, maybe I made a mistake switching. Please help me if any of you have a solution, I have invested quite a lot blindly trusting Google. :(

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7774/suggestions-for-syncing-data-to-someone-besides-google-funambol

Comment: Related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6677/how-can-i-control-the-frequency-of-synchronization-with-google and http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8025/can-i-use-the-google-market-without-syncing-other-google-data.

Comment: If you don't want to be tied in to Google, why would you choose an Android phone?

Comment: You need to be explicit about what exactly you're trying to sync ... I don't know of anything on my PC that requires GMail to sync.

Answer (score 4):

You can easily limit what data is synced by navigating to Settings > Accounts and Sync. ( Your menu may look somewhat different than this but should be similar.) From there you can deselect Background Data, Auto-Sync as well as individual accounts such as your Google (@gmail), Facebook, etc. However, I believe this will just prevent syncing from occurring automatically. If you open the GMail application, I believe it will sync your inbox/outbox/etc. BUT, if you're not using GMail, this wouldn't apply to you.

While you're at it, you can navigate to Settings > Connect to PC > Default Connection Type. There you may have another option regarding Syncing (with a PC). I see "HTC Sync" but I'm not certain what other manufacturers have in that menu.

Answer (score -1):

This is what I did to solve this Google forcing on me problem.

This method will most likely **void your warranty** for your device proceed at your own risk.

First of all my phone was already rooted so, I did not need to root my phone. So you will need to root your phone. You will need to install titanium backup on to your rooted phone and run a full backup of your phone apps. Then you will need to look for a file called **Google Contact Sync** and uninstalled/or freeze it. It is also wise to install droidwall firewall or even Avast mobile firewall. Now I have to do something about calendar syncing to Gmail, None!